# Ruby Lingua::Stem alternative

Tags: ruby, stemming

Is there a free alternative of Perl Lingua::Stem module, able to handle Russian language? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer

Удачи )